# COUNTIF with multiple data points

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having some trouble figuring out a formula for Google Spreadsheets. Am getting answers but they're not counting what I'd like. I've pasted an example scenario below:

[image: example scenario]

Here's the report I'm trying to generate:

[image: report I'm trying to generate]

Here's what I'm trying to do:

For all listings of `Lisinopril` (listed as either by itself or with other drugs in column A), how many times are efficacy (or safety) mentioned?

Each efficacy parameter (or safety) should be counted individually, e.g. Lisinopril Efficacy:

```
Row 2, Column B = 3
Row 3, Column B = 3
Row 7, Column B = 1
Total = 7
```

The current formula I have for Lisinopril Efficacy is:

```
=counta(filter(A:A="*lisinopril*"),B:B,{"*bp lowering*","*kidney sparing*","*heart rate*"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a crude answer, but I recreated your Drug, Efficacy, and Safety columns and started plugging away at how it should properly count items inside each column.

***What I noticed:*** items inside the Efficacy and Safety columns were single cells, with values separated by commas.

This means that we can use the SPLIT function to count each individual item inside the cell, without really having to call out each specific listed item for Efficacy or Safety.

What it looks like:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, SEARCH("*Lisinopril*", A:A))), ","))
```

Let me walk through it for you, starting from the inside.

```
SEARCH("*Lisinopril*", A:A)
```

Using the [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094154?hl=en) function, you can use wildcards, as you have, to search for blocks of text within a cell. It also allows us to search, with wildcards, using FILTER, which does not support wildcards.

```
JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, SEARCH("*Lisinopril*", A:A)))
```

Using [JOIN](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077?hl=en) to squash them all into one cell and separating the values from each cell with a comma. In your example, the joined cell would Lisinopril would look like this:

```
BP Lowering, Kidnery Sparing, Heart Rate,BP Lowering, Kidnery Sparing, Heart Rate,Heart Rate
```

The odd spading in that is because I delimited with "," without any spaces, just as a heads up.

Now that we have a single cell with all of your values from the column, you can split them (using [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094136?hl=en)!) and count the number of values of the split using [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093991?hl=en).

You'll have to do this for each type of drug that is listed, along with changing the filter to look at the third column for Safety numbers, but it appears to work from my initial testing.

I've linked to each Google Sheets function upon my first mention of each, so do feel free to click through and read up on my implementation!

Let me know how this goes for you!

**EDIT:** Removed TRANSPOSE as it was unnecessary, and I also went through with a generic example on [my personal blog](http://jonlim.ca/2014/04/google-spreadsheets-count-multiple-data-points/), just in case you need a potentially simpler explanation!